# Extract specific columns from text file

Tags: awk, csv, text

There is a text file, with aboot 10000+ lines, in the format:

`field1 field2 field3 field4 field5 ... fieldX`

It needs to be converted to look like:

`field1,field2,field4,field3,field5 to fieldX`

The last field must contain everything from field5 until the end of the line. And the final output must be exported to a csv file.

Therefore, for:

`123 abc XYZ qwe Abcd Efgh Iklmno Pqr Stu`

The output should look like:

`123,abc,qwe,XYZ,Abcd Efgh Iklmno Pqr Stu`

This is what I am using to try and achieve the desired output:

`awk '{printf $1 "," $2 "," $4 "," $3 ",";{for(i=5; i<NF; i++) printf "%s",$i OFS; if(NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS}}' file.txt > file1.txt`

`(echo "Heading1,H2,H3,H4,H5" ; cat file1.txt) > file.csv`

The desired output is generating a new line at the end of every entry, I am not entirely sure why. I am very new to awk and Unix, in general. Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: Works fine for me.  Can you provide more details.

Comment: There is another step that send this file via mail:

`mutt -a "/path/to/file1.csv"  -- user@domain.com`

The resultant csv file has a blank line at the end of every entry.
So, there is a row with data, then a blank row, another row of data followed by a blank row.. and so on.

Comment: So, if you run `cat /path/to/file1.csv`, do you see those blank lines?  Or, do you just see them in the email?

Comment: No, there are no blank lines seen when cat file1.csv is run.

The email is sent to a recipient using a Windows machine. When the file is opened on Microsoft Excel, the blanks are seen.

Comment: John, I found this article which helped me fix my issue:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021982/awk-without-printing-newline).

@danben says _The ORS (output record separator) variable in AWK defaults to "\n" and is printed after every line. You can change it to " "_.

Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here [awk without printing newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021982/awk-without-printing-newline).

*The ORS (output record separator) variable in AWK defaults to "\n" and is printed after every line.*